# How do you conditionally modify/update an object in django?

Tags: django

I'm looking to create/update an object in Django. My current code shown below:

```
SlotFilling.objects.create(
 originator=textobject.originator,
 empty_slot=True,
)
```

Where `originator` is set as my `primary key`. This works fine for creating new objects for the first time the `originator` is seen. However, I'm wondering how do I update the object if the `originator` has already exists in the DB. Basically if `primary key` already exists `update` functionality, but if it doesn't then `create` functionality.

I'm looking for an alternative to `.create` here. I couldn't find how to do this in the [models documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/). Is it possible? I know I could use try/except but I am wondering if django has an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

```
SlotFilling.objects.update_or_create(originator=textobject.originator, defaults = {empty_slot: True} )
```

> The update_or_create method tries to fetch an object from database
>   based on the given kwargs. If a match is found, it updates the fields
>   passed in the defaults dictionary.

Comment: As there a reason to state `, defaults = {empty_slot: True} ` instead of just `,empty_slot=True`? Curious because of the other answer on the question. Thanks!

Comment: just saw your comment on the other answer. Thanks for clarifying with this answer!

Comment: attached link to documentation also

Answer (score 1):

Try: Django's builtin function `update_or_create` for this.

```
SlotFilling.objects.update_or_create(originator=textobject.originator, defaults = {empty_slot: True})
```

Comment: This solution won't give him desired results as it will try to create new element if he has row with same originator and empty_slot set to false

Comment: @hackerman, Thanks for that. Actually I  missed that. Thanks.